# $_GET shows also another page

Tags: php, mysql

I've discoverd a bug into my script. I will try to explain it.

I've made 2 pages into category.php

This one here below shows all content related to a category:

`/category.php?nameID=Test`

When I go to the first content related to this category for example:

`/category.php?nameID=Test&id=2` I receive information from MYSQL about post ID 2, also all posts related to that category named 'test' below. Which I clearly don't want to get. only the Post ID

```
                 <?php
            // BEGIN OF SHOWING CONTENT PAGE
            if (isset($_GET['id'])){

            $naamID = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['nameID']);
            $id     = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
            $idnext = $id + 1;
            $gn     = (" SELECT * FROM category WHERE name='".$naamID."'") or die(mysql_error());
            $go     = (" SELECT * FROM post WHERE id='".$id."'") or die(mysql_error());
            $gnn    = mysql_query($gn) or die(mysql_error());
            $goo    = mysql_query($go) or die(mysql_error());
            $gnnn   = mysql_fetch_array($gnn);
            $gooo   = mysql_fetch_array($goo);
            ?>


            <?php
            echo '<p>';
            if(empty($gooo['youtube'])){
            } else {
            ?>              <h1> <?php echo htmlspecialchars($gooo["title"]); ?> </h1><br />
            <?php
            $fullurl1 = $gooo['youtube'];
            $videoid1=substr($fullurl1,-11);
            ?>
            <?php
            echo '<p><a href="/editpost.php?id='.$gooo['id'].'"><i>Edit this post</i></a><br />';
            echo '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/'.$videoid1.'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe><br />';
            echo '</p>';

            }

            if(empty($gooo['pic'])){
            } else {
            ?> <h1> <?php echo htmlspecialchars($gooo["title"]); ?> </h1><br />
            <?php
            echo '<p><a href="/editpost.php?id='.$gooo['id'].'"><i>Edit this post</i></a><br />';
            echo '<img src="'.$gooo["pic"].'" style="max-height: auto; max-width: 600px;"/><br></p>';
            }
            echo '</p>'; 

            }
            ?>
```

Comment: i didnt get you question. What is the script printing.. and what do you want it to print?

Comment: what are you getting in $gooo array

Comment: @GauravParashar It leads to `$go     = (" SELECT * FROM post WHERE id='".$id."'") or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: @vp_arth ? Could you give me more information?

Comment: Whats with the `or die(mysql_error());` after the sql string? Your code is very [smelly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell)..

Comment: no)) there is not some `all posts` printing in provided code.. Also, you perform request `$gn,$gnn,$gnnn` and don't use it anywhere...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know what you exactly want please be specific

But your code should be like this ->

```
$gnn    = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM category WHERE name='$naamID'") or die(mysql_error());
$goo    = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM post WHERE id= $id ") or die(mysql_error());
$gnnn   = mysql_fetch_array($gnn);
$gooo   = mysql_fetch_array($goo);
```

The above code will fetch only one row from each table. Also you had put `$id` in single quotes that makes it a string
Comment below if you need more help

Comment: I will explain it, I go to this page: `/category.php?nameID=Test` I see there clickable urls related to this category 'test' example: `first content link`, `second content link` ectra... When I go to `first content link` I see all information related to the `first content link` and below that I see this: `first content link`, `second content link` ectra... which I ofcourse don't want. It seems they are combinated.

Comment: Use the above code and tell me the result.Also do a `print_r()` on `$gnnn` and `$gooo` and tell me the result

Comment: still the same, How can I pm you so I can give you my site maybe you will understand better what I mean

Comment: I've used `    print_r($gnnn   = mysql_fetch_array($gnn));
    print_r($gooo   = mysql_fetch_array($goo));`


The result: `Array ( [0] => 1 [nameID] => 1 [1] => Test [name] => Test [2] => 2014-03-27 11:22:08 [date] => 2014-03-27 11:22:08 [3] => TEST JAWEL [description] => TEST JAWEL ) Array ( [0] => 1 [id] => 1 [1] => test23 [title] => test23 [2] => [pic] => [3] => https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bZtinj4zAzM [youtube] => https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bZtinj4zAzM [4] => Test [cat] => Test [5] => 0 [NSFW] => 0 [6] => 2014-04-04 11:43:55 [date] => 2014-04-04 11:43:55 )`

Comment: the result is pretty messy use `mysql_fetch_assoc()` instead of `mysql_fetch_array()` and tell me the result

Comment: the results: `Array ( [nameID] => 1 [name] => Test [date] => 2014-03-27 11:22:08 [description] => TEST JAWEL ) Array ( [id] => 1 [title] => test23 [pic] => [youtube] => https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bZtinj4zAzM [cat] => Test [NSFW] => 0 [date] => 2014-04-04 11:43:55 )`, The whole category.php script I've uploaded to http://pastebin.com/Zu6p3k1S he is getting `if(isset($_GET['nameID'])){` and `if(isset($_GET['id'])){` together on one page.

Comment: Hey i have edited the begin of show content page, match the changes on the rest of the pages here is the link http://pastebin.com/BH6k3yQh .

Comment: I tried to set else { CODE OF NAMEID } on the last line of isset id, which succes I only see the information from mysql of the post. But I've still this: `/category.php?nameID=Test&id=3` this is the main page and when I go to `/category.php?nameID=Cat2&id=3` I see the same information as on test, but I need to receive an error like `'This post doesn't exist in this category'`

Comment: 1)Normalize your sql database ,2)Use sql joint. 3)To display error 'This post doesn't exist in this category' , do `if($gnnn   = mysql_fetch_array($gnn))` , the else part echo the error

Comment: Thank you very much, will look it tomorrow! If i can't I just start a new question thank you I resolved this problem.